# Is libevent is sending event when its every write is called?

Tags: linux, sockets, file-descriptor, epoll, libevent

I want to get one buffer that written in `fd` file descriptor with `write()` function using `libevent` library

not a stream of all written buffers.

I'm not sure that `libevent` is sending event when every buffer is written.

Here is my code.

```
void OnReadable(evutil_socket_t fd, short what, void* arg)
{
    off_t fileSize = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    uint8_t* buffer = new char[fileSize];
    read(fd, fileSize, buffer);
    // some another processes with buffer...
}
```

Is this will read every single buffer written with `write()` function in `fd` file descriptor?

or there is risks to read ***more than one written buffer (more than one `write()` calls)***

Comment: No. There is no guaranteed 1::1 correspondence between reads and writes by the peer. It's a byte-stream protocol.